# how to improve python JSON dump formatting?

Tags: json, python-3.x, diff

I'm dumping out some complex JSON with python and the formatting decisions make it very hard to read:
- line breaks at 80 characters?
- awkward line continuations?

with indent of 2

```
  {'intents': [{'enabled': True,
                'intent_id': 'common-intent-one',
                'training_phrases': [{'enabled': True,
                                      'modification_type': None,
                                      'text': '1.2 new expert phrase 1 without '
                                              'permanent_id'},
```

whereas I'd prefer more like

```
  {'intents': [
    {
      'enabled': True,
      'intent_id': 'common-intent-one',
      'training_phrases': [
          {
            'enabled': True,
            'text': '1.2 new expert phrase 1 without permanent_id'
          },
```

I guess the main item is to line break on `{'intents': [{'enabled': True,` and not to break single lines at 80 charas. Maybe this is an output formatter somewhere that is running as part of the Unit test?
I found the `maxDiff` option but nothing on line lengths
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.maxDiff

Is there a way to override any of these formatting options?
Or a more compact formatter for python that could be patched in?

I'm doing diffs on JSON outputs for tests, and so these little matters add up.

Another option is to use YAML I guess but that would be a big change for the tests. Post - bodging it with regex doesn't really seem possible.

Comment: Can you post your json.dumps code?  And a minimal reproducible example?  Here's a repl.it that shows the normal output that already matches what you want:  https://repl.it/repls/LiveAgedResearch

Comment: tx for the comment. actually its coming from a `assertEqual` inside a unit test so maybe test.unit is forcing some other formatting down. I did look into console width but coudn't find a way to modify the output

Comment: so I want to note that what you posted does not appear to be JSON, but native Python object syntax, so what it is outputting is the default formatter for Python objects?

Comment: this is a comparison from a unit test, so whatever the assert is outputting. Good point, you could be right, it's not json it's just an object dump. So that changes the question a lot :D